# Do you need Updatepanel and Scriptmanager in ASP.NET to get AJAX working?

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I'm finding that the scriptmanager and the updatepanel and basic implementations of AJAX for ASP.NET. I'm just wondering whether these were required to use AJAX and partial page update and referencing handlers such as button1_click on the server code page ?

Also if i can ask another question, I'm also wanting to know whether the updatepanel can support feed-in like facebook ? What I'm wanting to do is 
have something that updates the screen (like the update panel), and items within this panel contains links. When the user clicks on the link it shows a modal div, giving the user options to do some updates. Once the user clicks submit, then this makes a call to the server to update the details then also update the panel. Within the panel I also want to move some of the div elements using javascript (causing the drag and drops to save to the database).

I can't seem to accomplish this with ASP.NET... any ideas ?

Comment: If you can, use ASP.NET MVC. It will make your life a lot easier.

Comment: What's the difference between ASP.NET and ASP.NET MVC ? and how does it make my life easier ?

Answer (score 1):

there was a great article about using jQuery for that

check it out

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/ajax/AjaxAndAspNET.aspx

hope this helps